# Copy data from one worksheet to another with formulae as values

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm working on a macro that helps me to copy data from one worksheet to another in Excel with some conditions. The problem is that some rows contain formulas while I need the values.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  It would help if you post your existing code and explain a little more exactly what it is you want to do.

Comment: I started with this code below  i  need to copy data  line by line from the the first sheet (Workload - Charge de travail) to the destion worksheet(sheet1)  `Sub copier()
Sheets("Workload - Charge de travail").Range("A2:AG2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `.copy` and `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`, then it will paste in values.

exsample:

```
Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").copy

Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will make the copy and remove formulas, keeping values:

```
Sub copier()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, src As Range, dest As Range, i As Integer
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Workload - Charge de travail")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 2 To ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Set src = ws1.Range("A" & i & ":AG" & i)
        Set dest = ws2.Range("A" & i & ":AG" & i)

       ' ... you can add some checking here to check if the condition is met on the src range...

       src.Copy Destination:=dest
       dest.Value = dest.Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but its only for one ligne

Comment: the first sheet contains 10 columns same for the sencond sheet , and i have a drop down list in the column number 4 ( complete /  in process / cancel ) , i need to copy all the data from the first sheet to the second sheet while the clumn number 4 shows complete ( drop down list)

Comment: @RiadhSaïd i modified the code to handle all rows in the first sheet (easy to modify to 10 rows). the dropdown list will also be copied. However, it might be empty if the validation range dos not exist.

Comment: How is the dropdown list in the source sheet filled?

Comment: thanks i changed already , where i can put the condition for the drop down list ( i have to  copy only the lines with the drop down list displays (complete)  )

Comment: its filled with 3 options ( -complete / cancel / in process)  i need to copy only those who has ( complete)

Comment: good, so your condition is if `source.cells(1,4).value = "complete"  then` etc. did it work?

Comment: Well I need to go Riadh, I am sure that you are on the right track to solve your problem. Good luck

Comment: yes :) - i tried the code that u just send to me  i got an error its an infinitie loop   `For i = 2 To ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Set src = ws1.Range("A2" & i & ":Al1000" & i)
        Set dest = ws2.Range("A2" & i & ":Al1000" & i) `